# MongooseError: Operation `domains.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I understand that we need to use asynch and await while connecting db since models are loading before db connection happening so i have used and call the function in server.js Please look into my code and help me.

Connection.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
module.exports = async () => {
   console.log(process.env.DB_URL);
   await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        //useUnifiedTopology: true
        }).then(()=>{
            console.log("Database Connected");
        }).catch (error => {
            console.log("Database connectivity Error", error);
    });     
}
```

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const dotEnv = require('dotenv');
const { urlencoded } = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const dbConnection = require('./database/connection');
dotEnv.config({path:'./.env'});


const app = express();

// Database connection


// cors
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

dbConnection();
     
app.use('/api/v1/domain', require('./routes/domainRoutes') );


app.get('/', (req, res, next)=>{
    res.send("Hello From node aPI server");
});

// request payload middleware
app.use(express.json);
app.use(urlencoded({extended:true}))

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server Listen on port ${PORT}`);
});

// error handling middle ware
app.use(function(err, req, res,next){
    console.error(err.stack)
    res.status(500).send({
        status: 500,
        message:err.message,
        body:{}
    })
});
```

DomainService.js

```
const Domain = require('../database/models/DomainModel');

module.exports.createDomain = async (serviceData) => { 
    try {
    let domain = new Domain({...serviceData})
    return await domain.save();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Soemthing wrong: Service : Create Domain ", error);
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}
```

you can find full code here
https://github.com/vlpreddy/node-express-rest-api

I am trying to develop rest api's using nodeJs, tried to connect with mongoddb using mongoose. I am getting this timeout error since 2 days, i tried most of the solutions in the internet including using await and async.
So can someone please look into my code and help me.

Comment: I try running your code, I didn't get the timed out buffer error but the connectivity error, so I changed mongo uri to `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/restapidb` then everything works fine. Did you get the log message "Database Connected" first? If yes, can you give some detail of error trace. I usually got the `buffering timed out after 10000ms` error when I run the code not through the route but directly so mongoose instance haven't init or connected yet.

Comment: Yes before creating model, "Database Connected" message came. But after creating model I am getting this error.

Comment: Can you put full detail of error trace, it might have some useful information

Comment: I moved listen to database connection await so thought it will load after db connection, now the localhost is not working as db is not connecting,

Comment: await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        //useUnifiedTopology: true
        }).then(()=>{
            console.log("Database Connected");
            const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
            app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
                console.log(`Server Listen on port ${PORT}`);
            });
        }).catch (error => {
            console.log("Database connectivity Error", error);
    });

Comment: I meant the error message (including and come after) `MongooseError: Operation \`domains.insertOne()\` buffering timed out after 10000ms` in your console . You should edit your question and add it there.

Comment: @dinhit
Soemthing wrong: Service : Create Domain  MongooseError: Operation `domains.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Volumes/redmindstech/node/node-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:158:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)

Comment: Something went wrong : Create Domain Error: MongooseError: Operation `domains.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Object.module.exports.createDomain (/Volumes/redmindstech/node/node-api/service/domainService.js:9:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async module.exports.createDomain (/Volumes/redmindstech/node/node-api/controller/domainController.js:13:37)

Comment: Have you try create your database and collection first in mongodb (using CLI or GUI tools like MongoCompass, Studio3T), or check if they exist there.

Comment: I thought database will be automatically create when we call url, so that i can access it directly from Studio 3T as I was following tutorial. As I am new to mongo I have no idea, I will try by creating it.

Comment: @dinhit thank you so much for your help, I was not aware that mongodb needs to be install in our system before we do anything just like sql. I have wasted lot of time on this. All because error never said that mongodb has not installed. It is working fine now. Really appreciate all your help.

Comment: Yeah usually the database and collections will be created automatically but sometimes by checking/creating them manually help you find out that mongodb haven't created :))). I have once stupid time that figuring out why my mongoose not working then find out that i haven't passed the database name in mongo uri :)))

Answer (score 0):

Since I was stupid enough, I haven't installed mongodb in my system, so it was not connecting obviously. But I felt like it suppose to throw an error like

> dude there is no mongodb in your system, how the heck do you think you
> can create database and store the collections.

Any how people who are coming here with same error but a different reason can utilise following code and  connect database using async and await functions as new version can load models with out even caring whether database is connected or not.

```
**database/connection.js**

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
module.exports = async () => {
//console.log(DB_URL);
await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
    }).then(()=>{
        console.log("Database Connected");
    }).catch (error => {
        console.log("Database connectivity Error", error);
});     
}

you can import in any page and call the variable as a function 
since it returns a promise function which is written below.

const dbConnection = require('./database/connection');
dbConnection();
```

Comment: Yeah mongoose will allow you to work with their schema/model even if they haven't connected to Mongo yet.